# "unable to start activity component info" droid force close issue

Tags: java, android, xml

Here's the java code for the class

```
package com.warriorsoft.mtgupanddown;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int guy1;
    int guy2;
    MediaPlayer sound;
    Button plus1g1, plus1g2, min1g1, min1g2, plus5g1, plus5g2, min5g1, min5g2,
            GG, RESET;
    TextView g1, g2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        guy1 = 20;
        guy2 = 20;
        min5g1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // x
        plus5g1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); //x
        plus1g1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3); // x
        min1g1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4); // x
        min5g2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5); // x
        plus5g2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6); //x
        min1g2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7); // x
        plus1g2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8); //x
        RESET = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RESET);
        GG = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GG);
        g1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPlayer1HP);
        g2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPlayer2HP);

        min5g1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                guy1 -= 5;
                g1.setText(guy1);

            }
        });
        min5g2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                guy2 -= 5;
                g2.setText(guy2);
            }
        });
        min1g1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                guy1 -= 1;
                g1.setText(guy1);
            }
        });
        min1g2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                guy2 -= 1;
                g2.setText(guy2);
            }
        });
        plus5g2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                guy2 += 5;
                g2.setText(guy2);
            }
        });
        plus5g1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                guy1 += 5;
                g1.setText(guy1);
            }
        });
        plus1g1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                guy1 += 1;
                g1.setText(guy1);
            }
        });
        plus1g2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                guy2 += 1;
                g2.setText(guy2);
            }
        });

        RESET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
            guy1 = 20;
            guy2 = 20;

            g2.setText(guy2);
            g1.setText(guy1);
            }
        });
        GG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
            sound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.gg );
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Here's the layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPlayer2HP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="20"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPlayer1HP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:text="20"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="+5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:text="-1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:text="+1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="+5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
        android:text="-5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:text="+1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:text="-1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Guy 1" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Guy 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPlayer1HP"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:text="-5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/GG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPlayer2HP"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minHeight="140dp"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Optimal sideways"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/RESET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="RESET" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the logcat

```
01-16 14:01:51.292: W/dalvikvm(699): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.warriorsoft.mtgupanddown/com.warriorsoft.mtgupanddown.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at com.warriorsoft.mtgupanddown.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-16 14:01:51.302: E/AndroidRuntime(699):  ... 11 more
01-16 14:01:53.712: I/Process(699): Sending signal. PID: 699 SIG: 9
```

The problem is running the code on a phone.
It tells me that the program broke in some unexpected way and forces me to force close.
If anyone could please help me understand what i've done wrong i'll be eternally grateful
I am still new to programming and can barely understand the logcats
please go easy
Thankyou for trying

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the `ImageView` and casting it to Button.

check this line of code.

```
GG = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GG);
```

Change the type of GG as `ImageView` and typecast to `ImageView` as below:

```
ImageView GG;

GG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.GG);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this to this

```
GG = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GG);
```

to

```
GG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.GG);
```

you cannot cast an ImageView to a Button. Which is what you are doing